# Check whether Jlabel has Icon or not

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I'm having a big problem when I save an image to the database.

I have a `JLabel` called `personImage` and when the user wants to insert an image, he has to click on `personImage`, then a `JFileChooser` appears and the user can select an image. The selected image will be loaded into `personImage`.

When the user selects an image and saves it, it works properly, but when user doesn't select an image and is going to save the details, it gives a `NullPointerException`. I think  that is because there is no path to get the Image to File Object. How can I know whether there is a Image in `JLabel` or not? I want to check if there's an image or not.

```
try {
    String fname = txt_Fname.getText();
    String lname = txt_Lname.getText();
    String mobile = txt_mobile.getText();
    String home = txt_home.getText();
    String work = txt_work.getText();
    String fax = txt_fax.getText();
    byte[] image_detail;

    PersonDAO perDAO = new PersonDAO(); //create person object
    if (status == 1) // used status  for check whether Jlabed is clicked
    {
        File image = new File(path);   
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image); 
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1; )
        {
            baos.write(buf, 0,readNum);
        }
        image_detail =  baos.toByteArray();

        Person person1 = new Person(fname, lname, mobile, home, work, fax, image_detail); // call the person
        // constructer when there is an image. I did validate with status variable
            perDAO.InsertPerson(person1); // call the personDAO to insert the Person to database
        }
        else
        {
            Person person2 = new Person(lname, lname, mobile, home, work, fax); // if there is not an image call this constructer .
            perDAO.InsertPerson(person2); // then call to personDAO object to insert the person to  databasee
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        System.out.println(exc + "sssssss");
    }


    // >>> when click on the JLabel, the JFileChooser appears
    int i = jFileChooser2.showOpenDialog(this);
    try {
        f = jFileChooser2.getSelectedFile();
        path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(path);
        status =  1;
        personImage.setIcon(image);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        System.out.println(exc);
    }
```

Comment: The logical thing to do would be to store a collection of images loaded.

Comment: yes I want to store image if there is a image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a `JLabel label` then do this to check if it has an icon or not:

```
if (label.getIcon() == null) {
  // this means there is no icon
}
```